# Zapier doesn't send me an auto-generated target_url

Tags: php, integration, zapier

I'm trying to connect (integration between) my own PHP App to Zapier..

But got some problems...

As it says in Zapier Developer Documentation, Zapier should send me an "unique auto-generated target_url" to be used for sending trigger to that url..

[image]

This is the code in my subscription url

```
$jsonstring = json_encode($_REQUEST);

//echo $jsonstring;
system("wall 'test - zapier subscribe: $jsonstring'");
```

but the result is:

```
test - zapier subscribe: {"api_key":"ddfb"}
```

i expected the result should be like this

```
test - zapier subscribe: {"api_key":"ddfb", "event_name":"contact.create", "target_url":"https://zapier.com/hooks/123"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it...

Actually Zapier send me JSON Data...

So, in order to display the JSON data is

```
$jsonstring = file_get_contents('php://input');
system("wall 'test - zapier subscribe: $jsonstring'");
```